# WooCommerce lazyload breaking masonry grid

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, masonry

After activating the WooCommerce lazyload feature, the jQuery Masonry grid on the shop page is no longer working properly.

Is there some event triggered by WooCommerce's lazyloading which I can piggyback on and in turn trigger a reload of the masonry grid?

It seems like many people have run into this issue but I have yet to find an accepted solution.

I'm loading the grid in a standard way like this:

```
const $grid = $( '.products' );
        $grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $grid.masonry( {
                itemSelector: '.product',
                columnWidth: '.product',
                percentPosition: true,
                gutter: 32,
            } );
        } );
```

The problem can be seen at https://lasala.art/gallery

Thanks!